# How to fetch property in the template Django 1.8?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create functionality where it's clear whether the user liked every fetched post in template or not(so that I just check attribute `post.liked` which is True or False in `for` construction)

I suggested that method in models.py might help:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    who_liked = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='who_liked_QUESTION', blank=True, null=True)
    def _is_it_liked(self, theuser):
        if self.who_liked == theuser:
           return True
        else:
           return False
    liked_bool = property(_is_it_liked)
```

But I do not fully understand how should I fetch it  then in template, considering that it's a function and I need to insert request.user as argument to the function and call it. Could you please explain how it works since documentation didn't help me much?

Comment: You can't have a property that takes an argument. This doesn't work even in plain Python.

Comment: @DanielRoseman How can I implement the functionality I need? I need to know on every post whether it's liked by authorized user in oder to show whether it's liked or not

Comment: You need a template tag.

Comment: Note also that your model structure doesn't look right. Each post can only be liked by a single user, which seems wrong.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, ManyToMany may be correct here, right?